# next_posts_link returns same content of 1st page

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, navigation

Pagination seems to work fine... I have 21 posts... and it will go to 3 pages... however... every page shows 10 posts and the same content as the first page....

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'a-reports',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $wp_query-> have_posts() )
{
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>
<a target="blank" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Report</a>
<?php
endwhile;

<?php next_posts_link('Older Entries »'); 

//clear again
$wp_query = null;
//reset
$wp_query = $temp;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order [to get pagination working](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query) with secondary Loops, you have to pass the `$paged` parameter to `WP_Query`, other wise the query does not know which set of posts to load and will load the first set, page 1, every time. I got it to work by adding `'paged' => $paged` inside the `$args = array();`

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'a-reports',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
)
```